# convert string from money format to float in js

Tags: javascript

I'd like to convert a money formatted string into a float in javascript.

ex:
'$1,000.20' convert to a float 1000.20

'USD 1,000.20' convert to a float 1000.20

I'm also interested to know how to replace alphabetic characters to say '*'

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pick out numbers from an arbitrary string with regex:

```
var match= string.match(/[0-9,.]*/);
if (match!==null) {
    var amount= parseFloat( match[0].replace(/,/g, '') ); // replace , thousands separator
}
```

However! It's generally a no-no to store money amounts in a floating point type due to the inaccuracy of floating point calculations. Of course JavaScript *only* gives you floating-point numbers, but by sticking to whole numbers (eg. of cents) you get accurate calculations up to the odd quadrillion.

Best of all for dealing with money is to use a decimal arithmetic type. This isn't a built-in type in JavaScript, but here's [an implementation](http://stz-ida.de/html/oss/js_bigdecimal.html.en) of it. (It is, unfortunately, rather heavyweight... I'm thinking of hacking up a simpler implementation of just the basics for trivial cases where you only need basic arithmetic.)

> I'm also interested to know how to replace alphabetic characters to say '*'

regex again:

```
string.replace(/[A-Z]/gi, '*')
```

(for values of “alphabetic characters” within ASCII. If you need non-ASCII Unicode letters to be replaced you'd have to construct a much more involved character class... JavaScript doesn't have built-in classes for the metadata of the whole Unicode character set.)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I found that I wanted a slightly different regex: string.match(/[0-9,.]+/g)

Answer (score 5):

Long time ago I made an regex to handle all kind of currency ...

```
([+-]?[0-9|^.|^,]+)[\.|,]([0-9]+)$
```

Look the result of it

[image]

then you just need to get the fraction part, remove all "." and "," and concat with the fraction part if it exists

The final results become:

```
let currency = "R$ -123.324,123,323"
let regex = /([+-]?[0-9|^.|^,]+)[\.|,]([0-9]+)$/igm
let result = regex.exec(currency);
console.log("Regex result: " + result);
let floatResult = result? result[1].replace(/[.,]/g, "")+ "." + result[2] : currency.replace(/[^0-9-+]/g, "");
console.log("Final result: " + floatResult);
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/nicollaas94/pen/zdOevo?editors=0011

Comment: Thank you! Even chatgpt was not able to help me :)

Comment: Sadly it did not work as I expected. I ended up using https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-parsing and it's doing it really well.

Answer (score 4):

Remove all non number symbols:

> dirty_string.replace(/[^\d.]/g,'')

Answer (score 2):

this could work:

```
floatstring=currencystring.replace(/\$/,"");
floatstring=floatstring.replace(/USD/,"");  
floatstring=floatstring.replace(/,/,"");  
floatstring=floatstring*1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will remove all chars

```
      var value = string.replace(',', '');
      value = value.replace(/[^0-9,.]*/, '');
      value = parseFloat(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript [substring()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp) Method to strip off letters and then parse using parseFloat

```
parseFloat('1,000.20')

parseFloat('1,000.20')
```

Comment: Seems not to work 100% correct. If a do `parseFloat('1,000.20')` in Chrome I'm getting `1`as result